# Next.js Hydration Error: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <img> in <div> with next/image component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am working on a Next.js project where I have a RecipeOfTheDay component that renders an image using the next/image component. However, I am encountering a hydration error when I attempt to load the page. The error messages are as follows:

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Here is a simplified version of my code structure:

pages/index.tsx

```js
import RecipeOfTheDay from '@/components/HomePage/RecipeOfTheDay';
import DataFetcher from '../app/api/DataFetcher';

const fetchApi = new DataFetcher(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + 'api/v1/recipe/');

async function getRecipeOfTheDay() {
    return fetchApi.fetch('featured');
}

export default async function Home() {
    const recipeOfTheDay = await getRecipeOfTheDay();

    return (
        <main className="">
            <RecipeOfTheDay recipeOfTheDay={recipeOfTheDay}/>
        </main>
    );
}
```

components/HomePage/RecipeOfTheDay.tsx

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';

type Props = {
  recipeOfTheDay: any;
};

const RecipeOfTheDay = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className="relative mb-36">
      <div className="hidden md:block absolute w-[200px] xl:w-[388px] h-[150px] lg:h-[262px] bg-[#F3BC55] right-0 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2"></div>
      <div className="container mx-auto">
        <div className="flex flex-col-reverse md:flex-row justify-between items-center">
          <div className="md:pr-4 text-center md:text-left">
            <h2 className="text-[46px] leading-none font-medium mb-3">
              {props.recipeOfTheDay.title}
            </h2>
            <p className="max-w-[610px] text-base leading-6 text-primaryParagrapgColor mb-3">
              {props.recipeOfTheDay.description}
            </p>
            <Link className="btn btn-primary" href={`recipe/${props.recipeOfTheDay.id}`} >
              Zobacz więcej
            </Link>
          </div>
            <Image
              className="rounded-full shadow-card relative h-[410px]"
              src={props.recipeOfTheDay.imageUrl}
              width={410}
              height={410}
              alt="Przepis dnia"
            />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RecipeOfTheDay;
```

When i remove Image tag from the code it just works fine.

I would appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this hydration error. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this guide https://blog.somewhatabstract.com/2022/01/03/debugging-and-fixing-hydration-issues/